# Salesforce Apex Query for not including the record

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id

I have a requirement where i have written a Query to fetch the records from the Server. I want to modify it as per the business requirement not to include the certain records, Please help me out for this .

```
{` testobj = [
                SELECT Id, Cust__c, C_R_Role__c, Rest_Flag__c, FTest__c, Web__c, Type__C
                FROM testObj__c
                WHERE Customer__c = :cReocrdId
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                ORDER BY Rest_Flag__c ASC NULLS LAST
            ];`}
```

i want Type__c in Which there are two record ABC__c and DEF__c should not be included in the above query can anyone help me out with the above requirement.

Thanks

Comment: You can use `!=` and `not in` in SOQL and use `and` to combine multiple conditions. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm and the following pages.

Comment: Hi Ramrahul,  Is ABC__c and DEF__c are fields on the same retrieved record  or are they constants?

Comment: They are values stored in the Type__c field which is being retrieved in the Query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query

```
[SELECT Id, Cust__c, C_R_Role__c, Rest_Flag__c, FTest__c, Web__c, Type__C
                FROM testObj__c
                WHERE Customer__c = :cReocrdId
                AND Type__c NOT IN ('ABC__c', 'DEF__c') 
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                ORDER BY Rest_Flag__c ASC NULLS LAST
            ];
```